# Macro que compara valore e devolve a diferença entre eles

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Tenho uma planilha Inicio e outra BD, na BD tenho dados de varios tipos de carros (Nome, Tipo (Esportivo, Casual), Cor, Assentos(2 ou 5) e Preço. E na Inicio tenho 1 grupo de Botões de opção, com as duas opções de assento.
O que preciso fazer é pegar as opções de Assento que o usuario escolher, e mostrar na minha planilha inicio os dados e a diferença de preço entre os carros cadastrados que possuem o tipo de assento escolhido, mas eu tenho que comparar os carros esportivos vermelhos somente com carros casuais vermelhos e os esportivos azuis com os casuais azuis e assim por diante.
A ideia é mostrar a diferença de preço entre carros esportivos e casuais com 2 assentos, ou com 5 assentos, a opção de assento depende do usuario escolher.
Um exemplo do que quero que apareça se o usuario escolher dois assentos é assim:
Casual Preto com dois assentos -23% se comparado a esportivo Preto com dois assentos.
Casual vermelho com dois assentos -43% se comparado a esportivo vermelho com dois assentos.
...

Abaixo deixo o código que escrevi até agora:

```
Sub Compara()
Dim Tipo
Dim Cor
Dim Assento
Dim Preco1
Dim Preco2
Dim Nome
Dim Resultado
Dim BotAssento (A duas dimensão Bot eu criei pra guardar o selecionado pelo usuario no botão de opção)
Dim Celula As Object

Tipo = Worksheets("BD").Range("B4", "B41")
Cor = Worksheets("BD").Range("C4", "C41")
Assento = Worksheets("BD").Range("D4", "D41")
Preco = Worksheets("BD").Range("F4", "F41")
Nome = Worksheets("BD").Range("A4", "A41")


For Each Celula In Worksheets("Inicio").Range("A:A")

If Celula = "" Then

Celula.Offset(0, 0) = Resultado

If BotAssento = "2" Then


End If

Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Sei o que quero fazer depois desse if que parei mas não estou conseguindo colocar em prática, alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Deixei Explicado cada detalhe no código, veja se atende
[Download Planilha Exemplo](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Akj9oYIS_-lM82t5K6W6xbVCH1H-?e=f2fkj6)

```
Public Sub CompararCarros()
Dim Tipo        As String 
Dim Cor         As String
Dim assento As Integer
Dim ultimaLin, i, j, k          As Long


ultimaLin = Sheets("BD").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row ' Pega a ultima linha da coluna A
'i = 2  para inicio dos dados
assentos = Sheets("Inicio").Range("E2") ' pego o número de assentos na Aba Inicio
k = 5
Sheets("Inicio").Range("A5:E500").ClearContents 'apago o anterior antes de começar
For i = 3 To ultimaLin ' percorro todas as linhas da aba BD

If Sheets("BD").Cells(i, 4) = assentos Then ' verifico se o carro é do mesmo assento solicitado
    Cor = Sheets("BD").Cells(i, 3) ' pego a cor do carro
    Tipo = Sheets("BD").Cells(i, 2) ' pego o tipo do carro (Casual, Esportivo)
    For j = (i + 1) To ultimaLin ' percorro todas as linhas do BD a partir da linha encontrada + 1
        If Sheets("BD").Cells(j, 2) <> Tipo And Sheets("BD").Cells(j, 3) = Cor And Sheets("BD").Cells(j, 4) = assentos Then ' verifico se o carro é do tipo diferente e o restante atende (Cor e assento)
            Sheets("Inicio").Cells(k, 1) = Sheets("BD").Cells(i, 1) ' passo os dados para o inicio
            Sheets("Inicio").Cells(k, 2) = "x"
            Sheets("Inicio").Cells(k, 3) = Sheets("BD").Cells(j, 1)
            Sheets("Inicio").Cells(k, 4) = Sheets("BD").Cells(i, 5) / 
            Sheets("BD").Cells(j, 5)
            k = k + 1 ' pulo uma linha quando concluido
        End If
    Next
   End If
Next
End Sub
```